# Blockchain Consensus 51% vs 50%

Tags: blockchain, consensus

All explanations of Blockchain consensus algorithms refer to 51% as the minimum percentage for confirming nodes. Why would a smaller percentage not work, as long as it was strictly greater than 50%? Is this to avoid metastability issues in the consensus dynamics that could result from a percentage that was too close to 50% making it less decisive? If so, why not make it 52%? Is there something special in some tradeoff that makes 51% special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

51% is just a notation for (n/2 + 1) where n: the total number of nodes participating in the consensus algorithm. I agree that it is a bad notation, more precisely it should be something like 50% + ε.

In academic papers you might find relations with the number of Byzantine nodes f in the system. So for PoW consensus, n > 2f + 1 (which is equivalent to the statement that at more that half of the nodes should be "honest"). For PBFT consensus in permissioned blockchains, it will be n > 3f + 1 (which translates to honest nodes should be more than double of the Byzantine nodes, or using the "bad" notation, 66.6666% + ε).